# Why is my cfgrid showing extra space to the right?

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a cfgrid with 5 columns. The funny thing is, it's showing a sort of extra column to the right, but without any of the formatting that applies to the rest of the grid. I can't seem to get rid of it by playing with the width of the grid or the fields... How can I get it to go away? (It shows up in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome)

I'm attaching a screenshot of the grid to show what I mean.

[image: cfgrid with extra space]

Comment: it's not space for a scrollbar is it?

Comment: I would hate to know how much time I've wasted trying to solve this problem. I've been temped to do some Ext hacks of the CSS. I've used Firebug to find the problem and fix it in edit mode, even. However, when I see grids online without that problem, it leads me to believe there is a better/simple solution. I see this on various browsers and platforms -- both bound and static grids.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have autowidth="true" set on the cfgrid.

Comment: I've tried removing it and setting it to false, but it doesn't seem to change anything...

Answer (score 0):

Not having access at the code, I can only make an assumption. I believe you have your last column "centered" by using `dataalign="center"` within your `cfgridcolumn`.  But did you add `headeralign="center"` to that `cfgridcolumn`? It fixed my issue.